# corpus from twitter

Tags: python, twitter

I am new in twitter use as a developer. I saw that someone can download dataset using the ids of tweets. However the twitter API has a limit for download.

Is there any faster way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to grab a username's tweets, you can do this:

```
import httplib
import json
import urllib2
import pprint

def feed(username, messages=50):
    template = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?' + \
               'include_entities=false&include_rts=true&screen_name=%s&count=%i'
    url    = template % (username, messages)
    output = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    html   = ''.join(output.readlines())
    tweet  = json.loads(html)
    # pprint.pprint(tweet)
    return list(map(lambda t : t['text'], tweet))

result = feed('noelevans', messages=100)
```

Comment: @594380923 Do you have the username to go with the ID?

Comment: @594380923 I added another answer which would work in that way. Put all of the ids in a list and then you can pass the list to the feed function

Comment: @594380923. Yes, but if you went "slowly". The api is subject to the restrictions here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't have the username, you can do this to get a set of tweets:

```
import httplib
import json
import urllib2
import pprint

def feed(ids):
    result   = []
    template = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/show.json?id=%i&include_entities=true'
    for id in ids:
        url    = template % id
        output = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        html   = ''.join(output.readlines())
        tweet  = json.loads(html)
        # pprint.pprint(tweet)
        result.append(tweet['text'])
    return result

tweets = [277496833788489728, 276760134124969984]
result = feed(tweets)
```

Comment: @594380923 You can get datetime info from this by looking at the other elements in the dictionary "tweet" in this answer. To return the time, change the line result.append(tweet['text']) to read result.append((tweet['text'], tweet['created_at']))

Comment: @594380923 I added a line (in comments) to pretty-print the tweet dictionary - there are lots of other things you can get from the twitter message